# A player with the provided name does not exist in Minecraft Realms

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-realms

A few days ago I created a Realm with some friends, we played and everythign worked fine, but they dissapeared from the list of invited friends, so I tried to add them again but I get this message error:

[image]

1. Yes, we are both in Minecraft Java Edition.
2. Yes, the username is correct.
3. Yes, we are both in the same version.
4. Yes, I tried adding a famous youtuber and it was added.
   I dont why he was playing but then from one day to another he wasnt in the realm, and no, he didnt leave it, is this a bug?

Comment: You probably want to contact Mojang support. Did he by any chance migrate from a Mojang/Legacy account to a Microsoft account?

Comment: @aytimothy they did the account directly from microsoft, do you know how can i contact Mojang support?

Comment: https://help.minecraft.net/hc/en-us